# What are the practical limits for evaluating an answer for plagiarism when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, plagiarism

Yesterday I caught a review audit on an answer that was removed for plagiarism. The answer was quite detailed, and contained a link to another website. I clicked through on the link, just to make sure that it wasn't a dead link or some other form of nonsense, but I didn't really read it attentively. (Bad Monkey!)

Once I got dinged on the audit, I went back to the link and read it thoroughly, and there's no doubt about it, the answer was definitely plagiarized. I mean, the user basically lifted the article *verbatim* and posted it as their answer. So, no pity for catching the audit.

With answers like that -- which contain a link to another source of information -- it's fairly easy to evaluate the answer for plagiarism. My question is, for answers that *don't* contain links, how far should I cast the net when evaluating an answer for plagiarism. I'm not talking about detecting audits. If you click through the "link" on the review on every answer, if it was closed (for plagiarism or any other reason), it's immediately apparent and you can detect the audit. (Takes longer to get through the review queues, though.)

I'm talking about evaluating answers for plagiarism simply as a matter of course when doing reviews. I think a site-specific internet search of Stack Overflow with each of one or two (or maybe three, if it's a long answer) paragraphs from the answer is sufficient to detect plagiarized Stack Overflow posts, since if the answer was plagiarized, the top two or three search results have a *really* high relevance to the search term.

For plagiarism from sites other than Stack Overflow, right now I'm just doing an unrestricted internet search with each of the chosen paragraphs.

Speaking in terms of practicality, this seems to me to be sufficient to detect most plagiarism. Should I widen the search, and if so, how much wider can it realistically be and still be practical? It already takes me quite a while to get through my alloted number of reviews (and I'm one who *really* loves the "Skip" button).

All of the Meta questions that I could find on this subject seemed to be users bitching about the audit system being broken. In this case, it isn't broken. As I said, there is **no doubt** about the answer being plagiarized, I just wasn't paying enough attention. Which is a little embarrassing, because it took me quite a while to learn that the key to reviewing is "Pay Effing Attention". I didn't tag this with [review-audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-audit) because the audit is not the point.

Comment: From a reviewer's perspective, all I can say is *you get a sense*. For example, an exceptional detailed answer by someone with no reputation is often a marker. Technical writing takes getting used to, and it's *less likely* to come from someone with deep experience who suddenly decides to join SO. One sure sign is a great answer to *another* question than the one being asked.

Comment: @jpp: I agree with you that sometimes, writing just *smells*, and that, as an informal rule-of-thumb, lower-rep users might deserve a bit more scrutiny. But, I was programming for 20 years before Stack Overflow existed, so I wouldn't *directly* equate reputation with experience.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield "programming for 20 years" is *very* different from "professional technical writing for 20 years" (or even 2 years) - it's just very different experience - you can easily see that if you compare pretty much any answer by John Skeet (who wrote books in addition to being developer) or Eric Lippert (C# designer, blog author for many years) with post by almost anyone else on the site - the difference is usually quite large. So while maybe that brilliant new answer with no even minor errors is by someone who was writing for 5 years and just joined SO... but likely just copy-paste.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Some things that are potential plagiarism flags for me are

- A new user posts a wall of text that reads like a well written book or blog
- An older, upvoted question gets a new answer (often copied or restating another answer)
- A block of otherwise normal text has an odd, out-of-place link (common spammer tactic)

  > George Washington's white horse is just a myth. Instead, he rode around on a [chocolate sauce](//#) donkey

What you need to do is just keep your eye out for answers that seem too good to be true. Sometimes a new user will surprise you, but many times they're not legit.

## How do you catch them?

The key is exact match searches. I like to take a whole sentence that's different enough (i.e. not filled with generic words) and then you do a search on

> "My plagiarized sentence"

The wrapping of double quotes means the search engine is looking for that exact match. I recently found an answer that had this block of text that looked too good

> SIGTERM is a Unix signal, used to tell your program to quit (TERMinate). When you run your program in Xcode, it runs it within gdb, the debugger program, which automatically catches certain signals. The signal handling behaviour of gdb can be controller but I'm just now myself researching how it's done so can't give you details. In the past, applications on Mac OS or iPhone were sent Apple Quit events, I think, but the SIGTERM signal may be used by the sudden termination feature recently added.

Searching [on that first sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22SIGTERM+is+a+Unix+signal%2C+used+to+tell+your+program+to+quit+(TERMinate).%22) gives you [this answer from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790597). Raised a mod flag saying so and it was deleted.

I wish they wouldn't audit you on those, because it's something of an acquired skill to notice the plagiarism, but it's quite possible to train yourself to spot the signs.

Comment: That's the way I do the searches I refer to, but with most, if not all, of a (short) paragraph. Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I am sad the chocolate sauce donkey link goes nowhere.

Comment: Great tip on using the most unique sentence to search possible plagiarism ++1

Comment: From an optimistic viewpoint: Maybe it's good to have plagiarized posts as audits. Then more people can run into the audit, say "How was I supposed to know??", and wind up here. That leaves them better-equipped to notice plagiarism the next time.

Comment: And is there a reason why SO doesn't process (or pre-process) contributed content using a commercial plagiarism service so that SO contributors don't have to volunteer their time to do it (when there are so many other review tasks to be done)?

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do. Especially the part about identifying sentences that are different enough comes with experience.

Comment: @davidbak: You mean, besides the fact that "commercial plagiarism services" are, by definition, commercial, and thus would be incredibly expensive given the sheer volume of text that comes through SO daily?

Comment: @KevinKruse That's the hopeful outcome, definitely, but it's still unfortunate that it's teaching you on the subject *after* giving you the test, rather than before.